# Pure rolling between two moving sufaces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I know about pure rolling on one surface, where the ICR (instantaneous center of rotation) is the point of contact with the ground. But what if the the body is forced to roll between two surfaces without any sliding between any one of these surfaces? Like rolling a marble between your hands. I knew how to find the ICR using geometry and obtain the angular velocity, but how about the angular acceleration? how can I determine for instance the acceleration of the center of the circular object in motion?

Comment: Once you have the angular velocity from the geometry of the arrangement can you not find its derivative with respect to time?

Comment: I do not understand your difficulty.  Along with @Farcher, I think there does not seem to be a problem here.  Can you give a specific example showing what the difficulty is?  For example : sphere rolling between two parallel planes - if the lower plane is at rest, the upper plane moves with twice the velocity of the centre of the sphere.

Comment: @sir_weasels did you get your required answer?

Answer (score 3):

A ball of radius $d$ rolls (w/out slipping) on two surfaces. One surface moves with $v_1$ and the other with $v_2$ speed (in the same direction). The linear velocity of the ball center is the average velocity $$v_{ball} = \frac{v_1+v_2}{2}$$ and the angular velocity proportional to the speed difference $$\omega = \frac{v_2-v_1}{d}$$

These quantities are kinematically bound and hence by simple differentiation $$ a_{ball} = \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$$ and $$\alpha = \frac{a_2-a_1}{d}$$

Now relative to the center of the ball, at a location $\vec{r} = (x,y)$ the acceleration is

$$ \vec{a} = \vec{a}_C + \vec{\alpha} \times \vec{r} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} \\ 
= \pmatrix{\frac{a_1+a_2}{2} \\ 0 \\ 0 } + \pmatrix{0\\0\\ \frac{a_2-a_1}{d}} \times \pmatrix{x\\y\\0} +  \pmatrix{0\\0\\ \frac{v_2-v_1}{d}}\times\pmatrix{0\\0\\ \frac{v_2-v_1}{d}} \times \pmatrix{x\\y\\0}$$

You can find the location of zero acceleration by solving the above for $(x,y)$ when $\vec{a}=0$

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{ \frac{d^2 (v_2-v_1)^2 (a_1+a_2)}{2 ( d^2 (a_2-a_1)^2 + (v_2-v_1)^4} \\ \frac{d^3 (a_2^2-a_1^2)}{2 ( d^2 (a_2-a_1)^2 + (v_2-v_1)^4}} = \pmatrix{ \dfrac{a_{ball}\, \omega^2}{\alpha^2 + \omega^4} \\ \dfrac{a_{ball}\, \alpha}{\alpha^2 + \omega^4}} $$

So although the ICR is located at $(x_{icr}=0\;y_{icr} = \frac{v_{ball}}{\omega})$ the center of acceleration is at an entirely different location.The  location along the *x*-axis is controlled by the angular speed and the location along the *y*-axis by the angular acceleration.